# Selenium in ruby/chrome, Selenium wait will not function

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, wait

No matter what I try to do, the browser tries to run the test too fast before it has a chance to find the element that I am looking for.  If I put in a simple "sleep 2", it has a chance for the drop down menu to drop and load and successfully find the element.  But I am wanting to learn to use the Selenium Wait command.  I have tried numerous combinations of the below and looked all over the web for documentation or perhaps examples.  I have found plenty of firefox and people say that some of the things below worked perfectly in firefox, but for me and my project team mates, we can not get any of the waits, implicit or explicit, to pause long enough for it to detect the element.  The element does not exist until the drop down menu is fully dropped, then it can detect it.  It doesn't take 2 seconds but it seems that none of my wait commands will actually make it wait.  Like I said, I have tried numerous different things and almost all of them are below.  If anyone can help guide me, i would appreciate it.  Here is some of the code I have tried:

```
def setup
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
    @driver.get "https://website.herokuapp.com/"
    @wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds
    # @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for:chrome
    # @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
    # @wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 15)
    # @wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
    # @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10
    # @wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(timeout: 10)
    @driver.manage.window.maximize()
    # @driver.navigate.to("https://website.herokuapp.com/")
```

end

```
def test_user_name_is_present
    login()

    @driver.find_element(:class, "navbar-toggle").click()
    # user = @driver.find_element(:class, "dropdown-toggle").text
    # @wait.until{@driver.find_element(:class, "dropdown-toggle")}
    @driver.find_element(:class, "dropdown-toggle")
    @wait.until { @driver.find_element(:class => "dropdown-toggle") }
    user = @driver.find_element(:class, "dropdown-toggle").text
    assert_equal(true, user.include?('HEATHER'), "no user") 
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm more familiar with JavaScript or Java bindings.

But what about:

```
def test_user_name_is_present
    login()

    @driver.find_element(:class, "navbar-toggle").click()
    @wait.until { @driver.find_element(:class => "dropdown-toggle").displayed? }
    user = @driver.find_element(:class, "dropdown-toggle").text
    assert_equal(true, user.include?('HEATHER'), "no user") 
  end
```

Comment: I will give this a shot the first chance I get.  I do not believe I tried "displayed?".  What happens is it clicks the dropdown menu then closes the browser so fast it doesn't have time to detect it.  But let me give this a shot and I will get back to you, thanks alot!

Comment: @wait.until.displayed? did work.  It might have been the solution we were wanting.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Our team uses this, just add to your test_helper.rb if using rails

```
def wait_for_ajax(sleep_sec = 4)
  assert page.has_no_content?(:css, 'body.loading')
  sleep sleep_sec if sleep_sec
end
```

Comment: we have been using sleeps and we are trying to stay away from them, per the directions of our bosses.  They are very effective and have been very useful to us.  However, when it comes to running in headless mode, the sleep times all change around because it seems to run faster and we have to go back in our code and change every test to account for them.  But it was a good solution and we liked using them, but our bosses preferred us not to use them.